# react app needs to upgrade version of libsass used by node-sass

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sass, node-sass, libsass

I have a react app that is using node-sass (v4.14.1).
It looks like it only uses version 3.5.5 of libsass.
This white source scan I have says I need to update libsass to 3.6.0

I am really struggling with what the path to fixing this is.

Has anyone else had the same problem and had to resolve or have some clear steps to follow to remedy this?

### Thanks in advance,